# In-App Purchase set up struggle + StoreKit

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm currently struggling quite a lot setting up one In-App Purchase for my iPhone app using StoreKit as well.

I'm actually using the `StoreManager` template from BLCKBIRDS: https://github.com/BLCKBIRDS/Treasure-Store---In-App-Purchases-in-SwiftUI/blob/master/Treasure%20Store/Treasure%20Store/StoreManager.swift

And I just want to extract the `HStack` from the `List`:

```
List(storeManager.myProducts, id: \.self) { product in

    HStack {

        VStack {
            Text(product.localizedTitle)
            Text(product.localizedDescription)
        }
        Spacer()

        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: product.productIdentifier) {
            Text("Purchased")
        } else {
            Button(action: {
                storeManager.purchaseProduct(product: product)
            }, label: {
                Text("Buy for \(product.price) $")
            })
        }

    }

}
```

But in that case, I dont' know how to replace `product` as I don't have a List or a ForEach to get `product in`:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: /* What to write here? */) {
    Text("Purchased")
} else {
    Button(action: {
        storeManager.purchaseProduct(product: /* What to write here? */)
    }, label: {
        Text("Buy for \(/* What to write here? */) $")
    })
}
```

Do you have any idea? I hope that my problem is clear... Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum Actually, I thought the MRE was very simple: you just had to copy/paste the 3 files from the link above. This way, I don't have to create a huge SO post?

Comment: SO is about helping the many, the code within a link isn’t searchable on SO and it can change/break, it doesn’t benefit the many to use links on a question. Maybe someone else will be willing to look at link. IMO if creating a bare bones example to ask for help is to much for the OP then the effort to create a solution is too much for me.